# How to load local data when you click on a listView?

Tags: android, xml, listview, load

I would like load local data when I click on my listView. Some images and texts.

MainActivity

```
@Override
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);   
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, schemeTown.class);
        intent.putExtra("town_name_dev", sparseArray.get(position));
        this.startActivity(intent);
    }
```

schemeTown

```
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String townNameDev = intent.getStringExtra("town_name_dev");
        //setContentView(R.layout.townNameDev);
    }
```

But I can't do this, setContentView(R.layout.townNameDev); so I create Xml files in assets repositery and use Dom

I create, but I don't know how to load the string resources files. I need this to do a multi-language app :

```
<town>
<name>I want to refer to my string resources (@string/france)</name>
    <monument>
        <img>file:///android_res/drawable/eiffel_tower.png</img>
        <description>I want to refer to my string resources (@string/eiffel_tower)</description>
    </monument>
```

Answer (score 0):

The appropriate set of resources is loaded by Android when your app is started.  If that set changes (for instance, the device is rotated from portrait to landscape), Android reloads the proper resources and your app is restarted.  This is probably not how you want to handle this problem.  However, you can [load resources by name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13922717/getting-layout-id-from-string-wont-work) and add them to your layout.

Comment: Thanks you very much. I create an xml file and do this : `int resID = this.getResources().getIdentifier(townNameDev, "layout", this.getPackageName()); LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(resID);` But how I can display the layout ? I tried layout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); but I had a NullPointerException --'